# Making Styled Components DRYer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

When it comes to checking for props in Styled Components, it seems to me that things could be a great deal DRYer.

For instance, let's take a look at the following code:

```
  ${props => props.white && `color: ${colors.white}`}
  ${props => props.light && `color: ${colors.light}`}
  ${props => props.grey && `color: ${colors.grey.base}`}
  ${props => props.dark && `color: ${colors.dark}`}
  ${props => props.black && `color: ${colors.black}`}

  ${props => props.info && `color: ${colors.info}`}
  ${props => props.success && `color: ${colors.success}`}
  ${props => props.warning && `color: ${colors.warning}`}
  ${props => props.error && `color: ${colors.error}`}
  ${props => props.link && `color: ${colors.link.base}`}
```

This is for a `<Text>` component that I'm creating - it simply checks changes the color of the text depending on which prop I use.  For instance: `<Text light>` will give it the `light` color that I set up in my `colors` object from my variables file.

Now, this code is rather repetitive.  The only thing that changes on each line is the color name -- otherwise it's exactly the same.

Any ideas on how I can make this code DRYer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, what happens if the user adds `white` and `black` to the props? What color should it be?

```
${props => Object.keys(props).filter(x => colors[x]).map(y => `color: ${colors[y]}`).join(' ')}
```

This way, you are filtering the props that is in `colors`, add the style text to it and `.join` is to convert the array into a string.

It will work ok if only one prop that is in color is passed, but if more than one is passed, it will go in the last color of `.map`.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm going to check this out.

Comment: In terms of adding two props -- I'm not too worried about that.  A text component should have only one color -- and so a user (in this case me), should make sure not to add more than one color prop.  If they accidentally do, then they will just have to go back and choose which color they want.  I see it as no different than accidentally adding `color: white; color: black;` to ones style sheet.

Comment: It works very well -- thanks.  With that said, I am wondering how I could do something similar, but with props that take a value.  Such as `size=xs` (where I could have multiple options, xs, sm, md, lg, xl, etc).  Any idea how to handle that?

Comment: What do you mean by `but with props that take a value` ? If you want, you can make a new question and I try to answer it.

Comment: Sorry - meant to marked as accepted (I just did it).  In terms of my other question, I'll post a new question.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you get a chance, please take a look at my new question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56655592/mapping-through-props-in-styled-components.